# Server return CORS headers, browser still throwing Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: java, javascript, cors

I am newbie to java scripting and CORS and stuck with this problem for some time now. I did lots of reading but no luck. Client running in browser (Chrome/Firefox) and making a PUT request which is resulting in OPTION and PUT requests. Server is redirecting PUT request to another server. Following is HTTP communication capture between java script based client and java based server:

OPTION Request:

```
Host: 10.232.65.230:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://10.232.65.230:3001
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Connection: keep-alive
```

OPTION response:

```
Status Code: 200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.232.65.230:3001
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 13:48:50 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

PUT Request:

```
Host: 10.232.65.230:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.232.65.230:3001/ermsim/erms/1/edgedevices
Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://10.232.65.230:3001
Connection: keep-alive
```

PUT Response:

```
Status Code: 302
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.232.65.230:3001
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 13:48:50 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST
Location: http://10.232.65.230:8000/edge/ermsim/erms/1/edgedevices/1/config/edgeinputs/1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

However instead of redirecting to the location provided, browser throwing following error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://10.232.65.230:8000/ermsim/erms/1/edgedevices/1/config/edgeinputs/1. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Make sure that you use cross-domain.xml file

Comment: Is cross-domain.xml file needed? Server is returning proper headers in response of OPTION request.

Answer (score 1):

Do you send a returncode not equal to 200?

> The response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range
>
> - Apply the network error steps.

CORS has a limit to code 2xx: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

Comment: OPTION request is returning status code 200 and PUT returning 302. Sorry I missed adding status code for OPTION and PUT request. Updated in question.

Comment: I think the statuscode of the CORS-preflight and the actual request have to be the same.